# JavaFX ListCell selected color

Tags: css, listview, javafx, javafx-8

I'm trying to change color of selected items in ListView with CSS.

```
.contact-list-cell:selected {
    -fx-background-color: green;
}
.list-view:focused .contact-list-cell:selected {
    -fx-background-color: green;
}
```

But it works only when parent ListView looses focus.

I know that standard JavaFX Caspian theme uses `.list-view:focused .list-cell:focused:selected:etc{...}` selectors. But I just can't find simple combination that will do the thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default stylesheet modena.css defines colors in terms of "looked-up colors". The best way to change the style is to override the definitions of these looked-up colors:

```css
.list-view {
    -fx-selection-bar:green ;
}
```

will change the selected, focused color. If you additionally want to change the selection color when not focused, you can do

```css
.list-view {
    -fx-selection-bar:green ;
    -fx-selection-bar-non-focused: green ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As always it is better to view actual sources than to read documentations. In JavaFX 8 caspian.css I have found the solution:

```
.list-view:focused > .virtual-flow > .clipped-container > .sheet > .contact-list-cell:focused {
    -fx-background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: caspian.css is not the stylesheet used in JavaFX 8: you should refer to modena.css.